# Android layout "3 columns" imageview + textview + imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Maybe a simple question, but i'm trying to achieve such layout with a LinearLayout:

```
     ImageView                TextView                        ImageView
----fixed width--- + ---------- fill ---------- + ----fixed width (right align)---
```

the problem is that TextView maybe be take all the space on the right, making the second ImageView disappearing.

Comment: set weight for each one what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put `android:layout_width="0dip"` and the `android:weight="1"` for the `TextView` while having the two `ImageViews` with no weight property. This will ensure that the area in between the two `ImageView`s is filled by the `TextView`.

Comment: I assumed he has that since he's horizontally arranging views. Plus he mentioned that the only problem is the second view going over the third.